# jdpicker error: Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [date=29/02/2012]

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am trying to use jdpicker http://jdpicker.paulds.fr/?p=demo
to attach a dropdown calendar to my form. Unfortunately I keep getting the error as described in the title.

The javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#coldate").jdPicker({date_format:"dd/mm/YYYY"});
});
</script>
```

and the form line is:

```
<input type="text" name="coldate" id="coldate" size="20" title="coldate" value="" class="text-input" />
```

I don't understand the error, nor why it's showing - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you're using this over the jQuery UI datepicker? I don't see much of a difference between the two and this plugin hasn't been updated since May 2010.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UscYS/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#coldate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="coldate" id="coldate" size="20" title="coldate" value="" class="text-input" />
```

Comment: This is a much better idea actually. I did look at jQuery UI but I didn't want to load the extra files. In the long run however, it's actually turned out the better option - and thanks for showing me how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

its working just fine here

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2zLba/1/)

---

**Update:**

it seems like the plugin works with the jQuery version 1.4.4, **it does not** work with the version 1.5.2 +

[**Proof**](http://jsfiddle.net/2zLba/2/)

Comment: That was correct, although it's still quite buggy for some reason (calendar showing up in the middle of the page etc)